# Operating System Installation on Sun/Oracle X4270

Tags: linux, installation, oracle, sun

I am looking for the simplest way to install Oracle Enterprise Linux (from DVD image) on a Sun Fire X4270 M2 (which does not have a DVD/CD drive). I don't have kickstart infrastructure, and our jumpstart is only for Solaris, but I assume it will have to be a network based install.

<strike>I'm really lazy.</strike> I'm really lazy to replace a perfectly good operating system with one that I consider inferior. If I could, I would leave Solaris installed - I far prefer it too.
Any ideas?

Comment: I agree with the idea that laziness (properly channeled) is a virtue for sysadmins. However, bitching about OSes and what you've been asked to do isn't a winning strategy here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rip the CD to ISO then use ILOM virtual media to install.

Side note: explaining how lazy you are isn't going to score points with the SysAdmins here.

Comment: I'll look into that. I find the best sysadmins are surely the laziest.

Comment: I kinda gotta agree. Constructive laziness is the mother of automation.

Comment: @mfinni, perhaps confusing laziness for a proper appreciation of efficiently applied effort? ;)

Comment: Tomato, tomato.

Comment: Forgive my crude wording. I have subsequently improved it. (A little)

Answer (score 2):

Use a portable USB DVD unit. Or as mentioned above, the  ILOm interface.